# Codeigniter V4 not loading public resources

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am using CodeIgniter 4.1.3.

below is my .htaccess

```
#Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>


ServerSignature Off
```

options all and followSymlinks not supported on server.
Working fine on localserver

Front page is loaded but it is not loading css,javascript and image from public directory giving 404 error.

not sure what need to be change.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules file. Make sure to place this in your root directory. Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options -Multiviews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

ServerSignature Off
```

***JS/CS rewrite/redirect:*** You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: with above htaccess I am getting `net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, sure Pragnesh, I have fixed it, kindly have a look now and let me know if this helps you cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but I still getting same error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, oh ok, I believe `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` could be culprit here, I have added 1 more condition now to rules, please do check once, cheers.

Comment: getting same error message for too many redirects

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, ok, could you please do let me know if we remove(for time being) these 3 rules. `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]` from file and try once if that helps you? If this works then we will see on this problematic rule, let me know.

Comment: when I remove those three lines, I am getting 404 error

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, ok, please do let me know sample url which you are hitting? If that is non existing page then our index.php should take care of it. Let me know.

Comment: https://vihrmd.com this is my url and below is css file that showing 404 error
https://vihrmd.com/frontend/assets/css/elegantFont.css

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, ok so you are hitting direct css link? I thought because of htaccess Rules css is not getting loaded properly something.

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, considering that you have to serve your home page `http://localhost:80/` as an example with index.php, I have changed rules accordingly now, could you please do check once and let me know then.

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, could you please do let me know where is your index.php is present? and where is htaccess present? Looks like its not able to find index.php, let me know complete path and we can check it then.

Comment: Please check this link: http://prntscr.com/198uk65
this screenshot of public directory code is outside of the public directory, Codeigniter bootstrap code from public directory

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, ok what query string you want to pass to index.php? any other rules you have apart from these? I don't think you should get 404 for these

Comment: no not passing anything. it is working on localhost with the same htaccess but not on a server. might be a server issue.

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, ok if you could tell me paths like `/singh/test/.htaccess`, `/singh/test/index.php` in text form it will be helpful, let me see because 404 means its trying to process but not able to find files.

Comment: httpdocs/public on server
httpdocs/public/index.php

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, oh ok, I have added RewriteBase now, please try my edited rules once and let me know if these help you.

Comment: server domain is pointed to httpdocs/public

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, Sorry I didn't get it on `server domain is pointed to httpdocs/public`.

Comment: when I hit website url it will load from httpdocs/public directory

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, yeah that should be ok I believe(if you mean this is landing page of website), try it out once and let me know how it goes, trying my best to help here, cheers.

Comment: still not working trying on another server

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, ok sure, let me know if this works there.

Comment: after changing the server it is working with old .htaccess that I posted in question

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, ohhh man :) anything you found what was the issue? Will be good to know for knowledge purposes. Happy for you that issue is fixed now.

Comment: I didn't get full detail from the client, he just said there was some issue with apache on the server so domain is change to another server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options All -Indexes 
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

works well on apache but if your server is centos then use this

```
Options -Indexes 
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```